# Understanding Object Instances and Creation in PHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, phpunit

I've been working through Kent Beck's Test Driven Development by Example, and rewriting the examples in PHP as an exercise in learning the language.

Chapter 2, "Degenerate Objects", describes rewriting a class method and unit test to ensure a new object (in the example, the object is called Dollar) returns each time a method is called (in the example, it's called times).

So far, my class looks like this:

```
class Dollar {

public $amount;

public function __construct($amount) {
    $this->amount = $amount;
}

public function times($multiplier) {
    return new Dollar($this->amount *= $multiplier);
}
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
 public function testTimes()
{
    $five = new Dollar(5);
    $product =  $five->times(2);

    $this->assertEquals(10, $product->amount);

    $product = $five->times(3);
    $this->assertEquals(15, $product->amount);
}
```

The first assert passes. **The second assert fails with a return of 30**.

Conceptually I know why it's returning 30, but I'm not sure how to rewrite the times method to ensure a new Dollar object is correctly instanced and returned. How can I rewrite the times method? Why is `$product` not a new object instance the second time I call `$five->times(3)`?

EDIT - I found some examples of the book rewritten in PHP here at SO, but I didn't come across any that described this situation (or clarified, to me, why $product didn't have a new object assigned to it).

Comment: Because your second assert is also against $five, not against $product

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker - the original test (written in the book in Java) does the 2nd assert pointing to $five (in Java its written as: product = five.times(3) ), so I did the same with the $product object instance. I was following along as closely as I could. What should it reference instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning new object. However you are currently assigning new value to original objects `amount` property each time when you call `times()` method. Change the method to this.

```
public function times($multiplier) {
    return new Dollar($this->amount * $multiplier);
}
```

Comment: Had I stepped back and worked on setting up xdebug I would have found that. Thank you very much.